# How to post a parameter from a form in python

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I think this one is a really easy one for many out there, but I actually do not get why my script isn't working, well Im new on this so if someone out there the answer, I would be happy.

The form simply takes one param and posts it to the same form on the same page, but for now when the page reloads the param doesn't show, I don't know if it is the python thats wrong or weather it is the html, anyway I have no idea as I don't get any error messages...

```
import webapp2

form="""
    <h2>Enter some text</h2>
    <form method="post">
        <textarea name="text" value=%(word)s style="height: 100px; width: 400px;">
        </textarea>
        <br>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
 """

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def write_form(self, text=""):
        self.response.write(form % {"word": text})

def get(self):
    self.write_form()

def post(self):
    text=self.request.get("text")
    self.write_form(text)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainHandler)], debug=True)
```

Comment: Apart from using string interpolation - you should be using templates, but anyway - IIRC `textarea`'s don't have a value attribute - instead the content should be inside the `textarea` open/close tag

Comment: Yes I know, im following a tutorial, I guess we get to the templates later. Thanks for the reply, will test that directly.

Comment: @JonClements Yes it did work thanks, if you add your comment as a answer I will 'solve' it...

Comment: What request are you making to the app? eg, are you doing "http://www.example.com/?text=hello" ? (also - is there a link to the tutorial)?

Comment: http://www.udacity.com/overview/Course/cs253/CourseRev/apr2012 and its really recommended!

Comment: thanks - will bookmark that and see what it's all about later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`textarea`s don't have a value attribute - instead the content should be inside the `textarea` open/close tag.

eg:

```
<textarea>%(word)s</textarea>
```

It's worth looking into templating though, but you mention that may be coming up further in your tutorial so...